# Java Web App + Javascript - Update info on client's browser without a servlet call

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications

I have a problem.

My webapp has a notify engine where users are constantly informed when new notifications arrive... just like facebook.

There is a counter on the screen.

Notifications: 0 (or 1, or 2... etc)

To update the number of notifications, I have a script that constantly calls a servlet and, if the number of notifications increase, the counter on the user's screen increses.

The verification occurs every 15 seconds, and it is run on the client's browser through Javascript:

```
setTimeout(updateNotifications, 15);
```

Every 15 seconds, the "updateNotifications" function is executed, calling a servlet that returns the number of notifications.

Is there a way of doing this without javascript? Some thread that runs on server side, updating information on every user's browser. Can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As we know HTTP is Stateless so for Server it is not possible to track any web based client.
However if you are using Java as client and Server technology you can use RPC as best tool for communicating both way.

**Or you can use transport layer based communication in which client and server both knows the port on which each one is running**

In case of Browser based Clients now it is possible to Send data from Server to Client without a client request. **HTML5 ships in with Websocket which you can use with either ColdFusion or jWebSocket(for Java based Service)**

Here are some reference links
 http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1954-using-coldfusion-with-pusher-a-notification-service-powered-by-html5-websockets.htm

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270